# Adding rows when new user is created

Tags: user-registration, table, automation

How can I have rows automatically added to a table (26 of them) when a new user buys a subscription for my site?  I need to be able to have a table already ready for them when they sign in.  These 26 rows will be unique to the user who is signed in but I need them to be created every time there is a new user.  Does this make sense, and is there anyway to do it?

Comment: Basically I want to have a table already made with rows for January to December for each new user that registers.  These rows will have unique data for each user that has a login.

Comment: I assume I would be using 'user_register' but I then don't understand how to code to add the rows to a database....

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.